# Handle inputs on stdin in C

Tags: c, posix, libc

I'm new @programming and i have the following question:
My Programm start an command prompt: like

```
input>
```

Then the user enters an string, a command like `merge xyz.txt`
I've finally got it to run, that my programm only reads from the start to the `space`. So

> printf("%s", command);

`output: merge`

If the user enters a string, where the command isnt' a command or theres no value it should start again printing `input>` and also after a command is done, it should print `input>` again. I tried to put all the stuff into a while loop:

```
void cmdLine()
{
  char *whole_entrie = calloc(1,1);
  char buffer[BUFFERSIZE];
  int dummy = 0;
  while(dummy == 0)
  {
    printf("input>");
    fgets(buffer, BUFFERSIZE, stdin);
    whole_entrie = realloc(whole_entrie, strlen(buffer) + 1);
    strcpy(whole_entrie, buffer);
    strcpy(buffer, ""); //reset because i thought the programm uses old entries?????ß

    int cnt = 0;
    char command[MAX_COMMAND_LENGTH];

    while(cnt <= MAX_COMMAND_LENGTH)
    {
      if(whole_entrie[cnt] == ' ')
      {
        break;
      }
      else
      {
        command[cnt] = whole_entrie[cnt];
        cnt++;
      }
    }

    if(strcmp(command, "merge") == 1)
    {
      merge();
    }
    else if(strcmp(command, "close") ==1)
    {
      free(whole_entrie);
      dummy = 1;
    }
```

BUT:
It randomly does something else. Somtimes I get an double free error, or he is returning 0 or it shows the `printf()` of `merge` when i put in `xxxkdlf` and so on, can somebody help me please, I'm getting depressed about this damn code!!!

Greetings

Comment: do you really want to read from stdin or parse the command line args?

Comment: from the man pages:  The strcmp() and strncmp() functions return an integer less than, equal
       to, or greater than zero if s1 (or the first n bytes thereof) is found,
       respectively, to be less than, to match, or be greater than s2.

Comment: @GradyPlayer read from stdin.
@l drumm I'm new @ programming, does that mean, i can't use strcmp?

Comment: strcmp() Returns an integral value indicating the relationship between the strings:
A zero value indicates that both strings are equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using `realloc()` at all? I don't see here any reason for dynamic allocation. Why can't you just process `buffer` content?

In accordance to C99 standard:

> 7.19.7.2 The fgets function Synopsis
>
> ...
>
> The fgets function reads at most one less than the number of
>   characters specified by n from the stream pointed to by stream into
>   the array pointed to by s. No additional characters are read after a
>   new-line character (which is retained) or after end-of-file. A null
>   character is written immediately after the last character read into
>   the array.

Yet another point. Why so strange `memcmp()` calls? From `man memcmp`:

> The strcmp() and strncmp() functions return an integer less than,
>   equal to, or greater than zero if s1 (or the first n bytes thereof) is
>   found, respectively, to be less than, to match, or be greater than s2.

OK, finally (maybe) third. You check for space ('') inside `whole_entrie` to stop. But if you just enter command with `'\n'` at the end you will copy it including '`\n`' so `strcmp()` will fail to check your command.

Comment: ok! You're right about the `realloc`. I just tried and tried and tried and suddenly this evil construct was born ;). I changed it, I'm just doing with `buffer[FIXED_SIZE]` no mal,cal,real-loc!!! I recognized the problem with the strcmp. I changed it to `strcmp(command, "close") == 0`, but it isn't working. So if i enter `close` it doesnt recognize it :(   HOW else can i compare two strings?

Comment: Again look for fgets() documentation - you can receive it with `\n` after last symbol and so copy input word.

Comment: Actually you should check for `' '`, `'\n'` and `'\0'` to stop scanning.

Answer (score 0):

While you are `realloc()`-ing, the address of the realloc-ed memory area can change. But you don't assign this change to the variable `whole_entrie`. Here is the problem:

```
input = realloc(whole_entrie, strlen(buffer) + 1);
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not an good programmer yet, I can't find an workaround for this error! Maybe you can give me another hint, please?

Comment: I'm sorry! There went something wrong from copying it tho stackeoverflow (I had to change the variable names, because my teacher doesn't want to see the codes of his students in the internet (plagiarism and so on) the phrase is:

whole_entrie = (realloc(whole_entrie, strlen(buffer) + 1);